# Fatal error: Uncaught FatalErrorException: [MissingHelperException] Helper class FormHelper could not be found cake php 2.x

Tags: cakephp-2.0, form-helpers

Fatal error: Uncaught FatalErrorException: [MissingHelperException] Helper class FormHelper could not be found.im trying to setup my cake php project on xampp.

Fatal error: Uncaught FatalErrorException: [MissingHelperException] Helper class FormHelper could not be found. #0 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\View\View.php(907): HelperCollection->load('Form', Array) #1 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\View\View.php(354): View->loadHelpers() #2 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php(327): View->__construct(Object(CakeErrorController)) #3 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php(309): ExceptionRenderer->_outputMessageSafe('error500') #4 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php(213): ExceptionRenderer->_outputMessage('fatalError') #5 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php(190): ExceptionRenderer->_cakeError(Object(FatalErrorException)) #6 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(127): ExceptionRenderer->render() #7 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(269): ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(FatalErrorException)) #8 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(212): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(64, 'Array and strin...', 'H:\xampp8.2php\...', 2063) #9 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(970): ErrorHandler::handleError(64, 'Array and strin...', 'H:\xampp8.2php\...', 2063, Array) #10 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(943): App::_checkFatalError() #11 [internal function]: App::shutdown() #12 {main} in H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php:138 Stack trace: #0 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(212): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(256, '[MissingHelperE...', 'H:\xampp8.2php\...', 138) #1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(256, '[MissingHelperE...', 'H:\xampp8.2php\...', 138) #2 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(138): trigger_error('[MissingHelperE...', 256) #3 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(269): ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(FatalErrorException)) #4 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(212): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(64, 'Array and strin...', 'H:\xampp8.2php\...', 2063) #5 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(970): ErrorHandler::handleError(64, 'Array and strin...', 'H:\xampp8.2php\...', 2063, Array) #6 H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(943): App::_checkFatalError() #7 [internal function]: App::shutdown() #8 {main} thrown in H:\xampp8.2php\htdocs\Gositterz\admin\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php on line 138

Comment: You're trying to use Cake 2.x with PHP 8.2?